replicating STOMP Websocket handshake from Java to Python
I have a Java system that is running a websocket server w/ STOMP protocol.
I have a working client for Java, which uses the following code to establish the connection:
public void connectToWebSocket(String url, String userId) {     
    // prepare the STOMP Web Socket client     
    List<Transport> transports = new ArrayList<Transport>();     
    WebSocketContainer container = ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer();    
    container.setDefaultMaxTextMessageBufferSize(1024 * 1024 * 5); // set the buffer to 5mb    
    WebSocketClient wsClient = new StandardWebSocketClient(container);     
    transports.add(new WebSocketTransport(wsClient));     
    SockJsClient sockJsClient = new SockJsClient(transports);     
    sockJsClient.setMessageCodec(new Jackson2SockJsMessageCodec());     
    WebSocketStompClient stompClient = new WebSocketStompClient(sockJsClient);    
    stompClient.setMessageConverter(new SimpleMessageConverter());     
    stompClient.setMessageConverter(new MappingJackson2MessageConverter());     
    stompClient.setMessageConverter(new StringMessageConverter());     
    stompClient.setInboundMessageSizeLimit(1024 * 1024 * 5); // set inbound msg limit to 5mb     
    stompClient.setDefaultHeartbeat(new long[]{6000, 5000});     
    stompClient.setTaskScheduler(new DefaultManagedTaskScheduler()); // prepare the jwt
    String jwtToken = generateJwtToken();     // compose the http header     
    WebSocketHttpHeaders httpHeaders = new WebSocketHttpHeaders();     
    httpHeaders.add("Authorization", jwtToken);     
    httpHeaders.add("PROFILEID", userId);      // prepare the stomp header     
    StompHeaders stompHeaders = new StompHeaders();     
    stompHeaders.add("Package", packageId);     
    stompHeaders.add("itemList", itemList);     
    StompSession stompSession = stompClient.connect(url, httpHeaders, stompHeaders, new MyStompSessionHandler()).get(); 
}

I am trying to replicate the connection with python but I encountered some problem with the initial handshake with the following code:
def test_handshake(url, userId):
    jwt = test.create_jwt()
    headers = {
        "Authorization": jwt,
        "PROFILEID": userId
    }
    ws = websocket.WebSocket()
    ws.connect(url, header=headers)
    print(ws.recv())
    ws.close()

Did I missed something? I am not too sure about the low-level request content happening in python. Thanks in advance for any help.
